# How to use Special characters in Python?

Tags: python

this is my code

```
f = open('test.txt','w')

f.write("\N{Circled White Star}")
f.close
```

And I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/mc experiment/python/SkyblockSniper-main/df.py", line 3, in <module>
    f.write("\N{Circled White Star}")
  File "F:\programing\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u272a' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

What I expected

The `test.txt` file should have

```
✪
```

What i got

```
<nothing>
```

Comment: Is the issue that you didn't call `f.close()` with the parentheses?

Comment: @rchome, according to the error message, the error happened during the call to `f.write`, so the code didn't ever get to `f.close`

Comment: Works fine for me on macOS, python 3.9. You can try `f = open('test.txt','w', encoding="utf8")`

Comment: Ah yeah, it looks like the encoding being used is [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) judging from the filename of the error. I think setting the encoding to `"utf-8"` would do the trick, but I don't have a Windows machine to test this on currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try changing the encoding of the file you open. UTF-8 worked for my testing.**
You should also open files using context managers instead of the way you did it.

```
star = "✪"
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    f.write(f"\n{star}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Without access to the original Circled White Star symbol, unicode may be useful

```
star = '\u272A'
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    f.write(star)
```

Comment: `\u272A` *is* Circled White Star. (You seem to be misunderstanding what Unicode is. "Unicode" is a text representation and encoding standard, not a term for `\u` escapes.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @user2357112supportsMonica.